# Using a slider in a UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios4, uialertview, uislider

is it possible to have a UISlider inside of a UIAlertView, and when the value of that UISlider changes so does text or a UIImage inside of the UIAlertView changes accordingly with the UIslider?

Im trying to create an easy way to change one attribute of a specific core data object.

So in a UITableView, the user would select the object's whose attribute they wish to change.  A UIAlertView would pop up and the user would change the value of a UISlider to change the attribute of that object.  is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can add views to an `UIAlertView` through its `addSubview:` method. To increase the height of the alertView I personally use empty lines as its message-text. For instance: `@" \n \n "`

I believe there are other ways to alter the size of an `UIAlertView`, but I don't know them.